# zappa: A GET request to '/' yielded a 500 response code

Tags: http-status-code-500, zappa

this is my first attempt to use zappa, and it failed for some unknown reason. Saw some other similar posts but they do not seem to be related.

This is the zappa_settings.json

```
{
    "dev": {
        "app_function": "app.app",
        "aws_region": "ap-southeast-1",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "project_name": "zappa-app",
        "runtime": "python3.7",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-ttsqlve2j"
    }
}
```

These are the console logs when I run `zappo deploy dev`.

```
Downloading and installing dependencies..
 - markupsafe==1.1.1: Downloading
100%|██████████████████████████████████████| 27.5k/27.5k [00:00<00:00, 6.20MB/s]
Packaging project as zip.
Uploading zappa-app-dev-1605776315.zip (6.0MiB)..
100%|██████████████████████████████████████| 6.26M/6.26M [00:04<00:00, 1.49MB/s]
Scheduling..
Scheduled zappa-app-dev-zappa-keep-warm-handler.keep_warm_callback with expression rate(4 minutes)!
Uploading zappa-app-dev-template-1605776326.json (1.6KiB)..
100%|██████████████████████████████████████| 1.63k/1.63k [00:00<00:00, 4.49kB/s]
Waiting for stack zappa-app-dev to create (this can take a bit)..
 75%|█████████████████████████████████           | 3/4 [00:12<00:04,  4.12s/res]
Deploying API Gateway..
Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 500 response code.
```

Below are the selected logs I obtained from `zappa tail`.

```
Calling tail for stage dev..
[1605763766887] /var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.2) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
[1605763766887] RequestsDependencyWarning)
[1605763767181] Instancing..
    import cv2ask/app.py", line 9, in <module>19, in _call_with_frames_removeddule

[1605763829365] [DEBUG] 2020-11-19T05:30:29.365Z f468bc46-eada-4ce1-9cd5-e544e15cb8f1 Zappa Event: {'time': '2020-11-19T05:29:09Z', 'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event', 'source': 'aws.events', 'account': 'xxx', 'region': 'ap-southeast-1', 'detail': {}, 'version': '0', 'resources': ['arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-1:xxx:rule/zappa-app-dev-zappa-keep-warm-handler.xxx'], 'id': '325e4bdc-0ce8-373f-c1f9-7384ad9cc278', 'kwargs': {}}
[1605763829365] [DEBUG] 2020-11-19T05:30:29.365Z f468bc46-eada-4ce1-9cd5-e544e15cb8f1 Zappa Event: {}
[1605764006219] [DEBUG] 2020-11-19T05:33:26.219Z 03c0312c-2ae5-48d3-b447-7154ce9d9322 Zappa Event: {'time': '2020-11-19T05:33:09Z', 'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event', 'source': 'aws.events', 'account': 'xxx', 'region': 'ap-southeast-1', 'detail': {}, 'version': '0', 'resources': ['arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-1:xxx:rule/zappa-app-dev-zappa-keep-warm-handler.xxx], 'id': 'b99799b3-a358-b580-845b-bae3b3e4c598', 'kwargs': {}}
```

This is a truncated version of my flask app `app.py`, which included some image processing tasks, and then uploading to S3 & dynamoDB.

```
import base64
import json
import os
import traceback

import boto3
import cv2
import requests
from flask import Flask, request
from PIL import Image

import config
from utils_image import draw_on_image, encode_image, json2array_yolo
from utils_s3 import download_file, s3_upload

app = Flask(__name__)


# set up aws permissions
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', 
    aws_access_key_id=config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
    aws_secret_access_key=config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(config.S3_BUCKETNM)

dynamo = boto3.resource('dynamodb', 
    region_name=config.REGION, 
    aws_access_key_id=config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
    aws_secret_access_key=config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
table = dynamo.Table(config.DYNAMODB_TABLENM) 


@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def intermediate():
    try:
        json_input = request.json
        # Do some image processing
        # upload image to S3
        # upload processing json results to dynamoDB          
        return "OK" 
    except:
        return str(traceback.format_exc())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I realised that there were a few python libraries not installed properly in my venv, and that caused the gateway from launching.